# What's is the C# alternative for "With" code block (which is VB.NET only feature)?

Tags: c#, vb.net, vb.net-to-c#

I know that C# does not support "With" code block. But, how to write the following code block in C#:

```
string SomeString = String.Empty;    
With CType(Lookups.LookupManager.Lookups.Item(GetType(Lookups.SomeLists)), Lookups.SomeLists)
    SomeString = .SomeDataTableProperty.SomeColumn.ColumnName
End With
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

There is no "correct way", as `With` is not a C# feature - there is no equivalent.

Use a named variable:

```
string SomeString = String.Empty;    
var lookups = Lookups.LookupManager.Lookups.Item(Lookups.SomeLists.GetType()) 
                    as Lookups.SomeLists;
if(lookups != null)
{
    SomeString = lookups.SomeDataTableProperty.SomeColumn.ColumnName;
}
```

Comment: I get this error "No Overload for method 'GetType' takes 1 arguments".

Comment: That didn't work either. This works though: var lookups = (Lookups.SomeLists)(Lookups.LookupManager.Lookups[typeof(Lookups.SomeLists)]). Thanks again!

Comment: It was more of a type conversion issue.

Answer (score 3):

The `With` syntax of VB saves you the typing of the instance-variable. As C# doesn't have that 'with' construct, you have to type it yourself:

change this VB

```
With instance
   somestring = .Property
End With
```

into this C#

```
somestring = instance.Property;
```